# scholarships/fellowships/funding not available to Masters in the US and UK

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding

Is this generally true? If so, how to find those scarce sources of them?

Comment: please clarify your question. an intro explaining the problem would be good.

Comment: In the UK, from what I've seen, yes. If you don't have enough cash for a UK masters, I'd say don't bother and go somewhere else.

Comment: @ Alexey do you think a uk masters is very expensive? mayb an american one is more expensive

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what program you are looking into, the universities (at least in the US) should have grants and fellowships predominantly based on merit. (Some grants may be issued by the university based on proven financial need, but it is often not much and there does need to be a need). Your best option is to see what fellowships are offered by the university and apply early on, as most deadlines for the fall are early January.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any rough estimate of how competitive of each scholarship scales like? 1/3, 1/10, 1/100?

Comment: I cannot say, as it usually depends on the program and university. I would talk to the financial aid office and maybe ask more from an advisor of the program.

Comment: if i didnt get funding before being admitted, is there money available after starting school? anything other than RAs and TAs?